# Function returns nonexpected value

Tags: python

Here I have a code about robot path. Description of the problem goes like this:

The Robot

We have a robot which is located in an infinite plane at coordinates
(x, y) and is facing direction r, where 0 <= r <= 3. The possible values
of r have the following meaning:

```
      (north)
         0 
(west) 3   1 (east)
         2
      (south)
```

Write a function final_destination(p, s) where the argument p is the
current position of the robot, i.e. a triple (x, y, r); the argument s
is a string that can contain the following letters:

- 'R' ... turn to the right (for 90°)
- 'L' ... turn to the left (for 90°)
- 'F' ... go forward for 1 unit

The function should return the final position of the robot, i.e. a
triple (x', y', r').

Examples:

```
>>> final_destination((2, 0, 0), 'FFRFFLFFL')
(4, 4, 3)
>>> final_destination((2, -1, 0), 'FFFRFFFRFFFRFFFR')
(2, -1, 0)
```

I wrote the following code:

```
def final_destination(p, s):
   x, y, r = p[0], p[1], p[2]
   for c in s:
      if c == 'F' and r == 0:
          x += 1
      if c == 'F' and r == 1:
          x += 1
      if c == 'F' and r == 2:
          y -= 1
      if c == 'F' and r == 3:
          x -= 1
      if c == 'R' and r == 3:
          r = 0
      if c == 'R' and r != 3:
          r += 1
      if c == 'L' and r == 0:
          r = 3
      if c == 'L' and r != 0:
          r -= 1
  return x, y, r
```

And after

```
 print(final_destination((2, -1, 0), 'L'))
```

**I get (2, -1, 2) as a result. Why function didn't return (2, -1, 3)?**

Comment: The conditition `c == 'L' and r == 0` is `True`, so it changes `r=3`. Now the next condition `c == 'L' and r != 0` is also `True`, so `r-=1`.

Comment: use `elif` everywhere to go only in one if at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, in your first if statement

```
if c == 'F' and r == 0:
      x += 1
```

it should be y += 1.

You should make your if statements like if, else if conditions. Which in python is written as if (condition): ---  elif (condition) ---

Ex:

```
if c == 'F' and r == 0:
      x += 1
elif c == 'F' and r == 1:
      x += 1
```

What's happening that's causing the incorrect output your test case is falling into the second to last if condition, then since that updates r to 3, it falls into the following (last) if condition. If then else should solve this issue.

Comment: Python does not have `else if`, it is `elif`

Answer (score 0):

General suggestion: To take care of `'R'` and `'L'`, you can use modulo.

```py
if c == 'R':
    r += 1
    r = r % 4
elif c== 'L':
    r -= 1
    r = r % 4
```

This takes care of the 3 and 0 cases and makes the code neater in my opinion.